# stop when call is not from "aov()" or "lm()" in R?

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have an R function programmed to **stop** when input is not a call from `"aov()"` or `"lm()"`.

Below, I expect when using `fit3` as input, my function to `stop`, but I'm wondering why it does not?

**P.S.** The function correctly stops when fed `fit4`, BUT doesn't stop when fed `fit3`; WHY?

```
fit2 <- aov(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)
library(rstanarm)  
fit3 <- stan_glm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars) # This call is from "rstanarm" package !!
fit4 <- glm(vs~mpg, data = mtcars)


bb <- function(fit = NA){

  if(!(any(is.na(fit)))){  

if(fit$call[1] != "lm()" && fit$call[1] != "aov()") stop("Error") else "OK"
  }
}
# Examples of use:
bb(fit = fit4) # stops as expected ! because call is not from "lm()" or "aov()"
bb(fit = fit3) # I expect HERE to stop also; why it doesn't? !!!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the reason:

```
> !(any(is.na(fit3)))
```

[1] FALSE

is.na(fits3) returns a logical named vector. Maybe you tried to check if is.na(fit3$call), instead of all elements of the fit3 object?

Comment: it works for fit4 since it does not have an NA element. fit3$df.residual is NA, hence you get any(is.na(fit3)) TRUE

Comment: please see what is.na(fit) returns. It returns a logical vector(vector of TRUE FALSE's). why are you trying to check is.na(fit) ?

Comment: change your function's default parameter fit=NA to fit=NULL, and then at line 3409 change !is.na(fit) to !is.null(fit)

Comment: great to hear that.